# Беспорядок в метках на тему [ссылки]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8) (379 вопросов) с таким описанием:

> Используйте данную метку если Ваш вопрос связан с ссылкой/гиперссылкой

При этом метка [гиперссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0) (6 вопросов) тоже есть.

Также есть метка [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0) (31 вопрос), которою используют то в вопросах о гиперссылках, то о ссылках на объекты в программе. Кстати, метку [ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8) также используют в вопросах по ссылкам на объекты в программе.